# Jenkins - viewing live html file from nodes

Tags: jenkins, automation

I've started to use Jenkins server to trigger automation which runs on two nodes. The automation creates locally html file which present the status of the run. 
I am wondering if I there is option in Jenkins to point on those html files and see them in the build view while the automation runs, so that I won't have to remote to each node and locally open those html files.

Comment: Are these html files like your test build reports ? If yes, then yes you should be able to depending on the tool you are using. We use gradle and publish gradle build reports and view them in Jenkins console

Comment: Hi , no this is html file is that created by the python automation that runs locally on the node.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is not exactly what you are looking for but I can think of two things:

For the *real-time results* monitoring here are two interesting suggestions. I recommend you check out these awesome detailed tutorials

- elasticsearch+kibana:
  http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-real-time-test-execution-results-using-elasticsearch-kibana/
- influxdb+graphana: http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-real-time-test-metrics-using-grafana-influxdb/

For the *after-run results* report attached to jenkins consider using Allure reporting framework: https://allurereport.org/.
It is quite nice and easy to use and is open source with quite large community. It has a jenkins plugin so you will have a link (nice icon) for each of your run in jenkins. The link will point to allure report with all the data from the run.

Comment: Hi , thanks, but I think that those solution are overhead for my target. I would like to be able to see in the build page an html file that is created on the nodes. I suppose that this is just some plug in that I can link the path to the html file and it will be able to show it.

Comment: All I could find is some junit attachments plugin. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Attachments+Plugin. Additionally, I can think of just creating some simple logic that will add necessary info to the log that is shown in jenkins console. Speaking of overhead, I agree, however, if you are building some more or less long-life automation on a project some solutions may make your testing easier and more controllable.

Comment: How about this solution : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Realtime+Test+Reporter+Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

For users, the status of a build is provided via the Jenkins master. While the build is still running, the master has little knowledge of what's happening on a node, and even less is exposed to users via the GUI.

Notable exceptions are:

1. Console output
2. Workspace content

Option "2." partly fits your requirements -- you could provide users with a link like this

```
<your-job-URL>/ws/status.html
```

where `status.html` would be the name of the HTML file that's maintained on the node (proper Content Security Policy required for that).

However, this will only work for the latest build of a job. So, if you trigger multiple builds of the same job to run concurrently, then this is not an option.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any other "simple" solutions to provide what you need. With some groovy scripting that uses Jenkins remoting to access and then publish node data it will be possible for sure, but doing it nicely and integrating it with the standard Jenkins GUI will require some effort.